# Razer blade stealth crash

Tags: crash

I have Ubuntu on a Razer Blade Stealth, I am experiencing a couple of daily crashes.

What happens is that the screen turns to a shade of grey, and it looks like no input does anything, besides a long press of the power button.

I tried looking into system logs but I'm not even sure what to look for, I would love some advice into how to debug a problem like this, I have no idea where to look for clues.

It also looks like the crash happens after a few hours, so it might be something related to resources, but I'm not really sure.

I have opened a similar question on the same problem a while ago, but without any luck ([Screen turns greyish, no command seem to have effect](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863616/screen-turns-greyish-no-command-seem-to-have-effect)), I know there's little info here but that's all I was able to collect.

Comment: So I've found this link https://xipherzero.com/ubuntu-16-04-razer-blade-2016/, I've followed the instructions and as of now it's two days my Ubuntu is not crashing anymore. Fingers crossed.

Comment: It looks like it still crashes, but as of now it crashed only when Netflix was in full screen.

Comment: I can confirm the above, the problem went almost completely away by following that guide.